# Django Localization: How to do functional test?

Tags: django, localization

I've localized my site following the documentation.

Now, I've wanted to test this through the browser. But, I seem not to be able to figure out how this is done.

I am using FF and in preference / content / languages, added 'es'. I also moved it to the top of the languages list.

Then when I go to the site, I don't see anything translated.

What am I missing?

Thanks
Eric

Comment: I think you mean internationalization and not localization.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Django stores the language code in the cookie for each user. You'll probably want to make use of Django's `set_language` [view](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/i18n/internationalization/#the-set-language-redirect-view), perhaps at least in your development environment, because it's quicker than deleting cookie entries or destroying sessions. I used it to write a custom view that switches between the base language and another one to snoop through the site just to be 100% sure I'm translating everything.

If that still doesn't work, might want to make sure you've added it to the list of [`LANGUAGES`](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/settings/?from=olddocs#languages) and that you've added the `django.middleware.locale.LocaleMiddleware` to your list of middleware, because it's responsible for parsing `Accept-Language` from request headers.